# Recursive navigation to same component with history using NativeScript + Angular with ActionBar back button?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am implementing a file browser component using Nativescript + Angular.

```
NativeScript 5.2.0-2019-01-18-12822
nativescript-angular 7.1.0
```

I have a route with a path parameter and a directory view component that is recursively invoked as the user taps down the file system hierarchy.

route entry:

```
{ path: "debugfilebrowserdir/:path", component: DebugFileBrowserPageComponent }
```

I am using the observable pattern to subscribe to paramMap on the ActivatedRoute in ngOnInit():

```
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe( ( params ) => {
      let path = params.get( 'path' );

      // update the model with the entries from path
    });
```

This works like a champ. I can tap through directory entries and the view is updated.

I have the back button in the ActionBar:

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar" title="Files">
  <NavigationButton android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" text="Back" (tap)="goBack()"></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>
```

Once a user has clicked down into a subdirectory, I would like to display the parent directory when someone clicks the actionbar back button. I can accomplish this with a separate button but it just looks confusing.

The problem is when tap the back button no matter how deep down in the directory tree I am, it takes me back to the root component and not the previous view. I'm guessing this is because my directory view component is being re-used each time a sub-directory is displayed. (Verified as ngOnInit is not called again.)

My thought was that there has to be some way to dynamically push an entry onto the history stack or cause my directory view component to be created multiple times but so far I have not found anything.

Is there a way to manipulate the navigation history stack so that, on tapping the back button, I can re-display the same component with different parameters (i.e. in this case show the same component with the path of the parent directory)?

A related unanswered question [I have an issue with "history back" when navigate to same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821005/i-have-an-issue-with-history-back-when-navigate-to-same-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is use a CustomRouteReuseStrategy

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { NSLocationStrategy } from 'nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy';
import { NSRouteReuseStrategy } from 'nativescript-angular/router/ns-route-reuse-strategy';

@Injectable()
export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy extends NSRouteReuseStrategy {

     constructor(location: NSLocationStrategy) {
         super(location);
     }

     shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
         return false;
     }
}
```

and inside your AppModule you want to put this as a provider

```
import { NgModule, NgModuleFactoryLoader, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { CustomRouteReuseStrategy } from "./custom-router-strategy";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
            useClass: CustomRouteReuseStrategy
        }
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here is a example in play.nativescript.org

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=AspHuI

(I didn't make this, I am just passing on the info that I have learned.)

Also, if you only want certain pages to reuse the route strategy then you would need to make additional changes of code

```
 shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
// first use the global Reuse Strategy evaluation function,
// which will return true, when we are navigating from the same component to itself
let shouldReuse = super.shouldReuseRoute(future, current);

// then check if the noReuse flag is set to true
if (shouldReuse && current.data.noReuse) {
  // if true, then don't reuse this component
  shouldReuse = false;
}
```

and then you could pass noReuse as a route param so that you have an additional check beyond the default "shouldReuse"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this.